# Python3 How should I execute this complex shell command

Tags: python-3.x, shell, command, subprocess, os.system

I would like to execute this shell command through python, I tried to use

```
shell="ls *R1.fastq.gz|while read a; do b=${a%R1.fastq.gz}R2.fastq.gz; c=${a%R1.fastq.gz}R1.out.fq; d=${a%R1.fastq.gz}R2.out.fq; e=${a%R1.fastq.gz}.s.fq; echo "sickle pe -t sanger -f $a -r $b -o $c -p $d -s $e"; done >SICKLE.sh"

system.os(shell)
```

But a get a `SythaxError: InvalidSyntax` I make some research, maybe I should use `subprocces` ? but I'am pretty new with this, could we help me ?

Comment: Also you have to escape quotes in your command, or use single quotes to contain your string.

Comment: @chrisz  what do you mean by escape the quotes ? get ride of them ? but it will not work like correctly without them

Comment: One way is like this:  shell="ls *R1.fastq.gz|while read a; do b=${a%R1.fastq.gz}R2.fastq.gz; c=${a%R1.fastq.gz}R1.out.fq; d=${a%R1.fastq.gz}R2.out.fq; e=${a%R1.fastq.gz}.s.fq; echo \"sickle pe -t sanger -f $a -r $b -o $c -p $d -s $e\"; done >SICKLE.sh"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`escape`** quotes (add `\` before quotes in your string)

```
shell="*R1.fastq.gz|while read a; do b=${a%R1.fastq.gz}R2.fastq.gz; c=${a%R1.fastq.gz}R1.out.fq; d=${a%R1.fastq.gz}R2.out.fq; e=${a%R1.fastq.gz}.s.fq; echo \"sickle pe -t sanger -f $a -r $b -o $c -p $d -s $e\"; done >SICKLE.sh"
```

**`subprocess.call`**:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["ls", shell])
```